# How does List.Max() function work internally in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, list, max

We can use the Max() method in a List to find the maximum of the values in the list. But how is it implemented internally? Is there a way to see how it is implemented internally in C#?

Comment: Yes, the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,6ca1a80e1f22e519,references).  I've linked to the first overload, if you scroll down you can see there are many.

Comment: Any reason you need to see the source? MSDN explains what it needs to do, and if it doesn't, its a bug? (no downvote from me)

Comment: This can't be serial downvoting, since a user can only vote once on a post.

Comment: @Caramiriel MSDN documentation can be unclear, sometimes even wrong. Source code is always right.

Comment: @Caramiriel Just curious to know how it is implemented.

Comment: For non numeric types it uses [this](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,6bfc5de59f92263e,references) overload. It works only with `IEnumerable`s of `IComparable`, basically it compares the element similarly to the numeric overloads, just using `IComparable.CompareTo` instead of `>` operator

Comment: @JakubLortz Eventhough its true, it should work like its documented. If the runtime result is different than the specificiation/documentation, and rely on the runtime results, it may break in a future release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a reference source site: [link](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,6ca1a80e1f22e519,references)

Sample (one of overload):

```
public static int Max(this IEnumerable<int> source) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    int value = 0;
    bool hasValue = false;
    foreach (int x in source) {
        if (hasValue) {
            if (x > value) value = x;
        }
        else {
            value = x;
            hasValue = true;
        }
    }
    if (hasValue) return value;
    throw Error.NoElements();
}
```

Ehh, let `James Thorpe` add answer - he was first (in commnent) :)

Comment: I didn't want to answer, hence the comment.  I've actually voted to close as offtopic - "looking for an offsite resource".

Comment: `String` is array of char under the hood, so the greatest char is returned by `max`..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `Max()` function isn't, in fact, implemented in the `List<T>` class. It's an extension method, part of the LINQ namespace, that applies to any `IEnumerable<T>`, which `List<T>` implements.

Now, there are several implementations of Max() out there.

- The first is the reference implementation Microsoft released as part of the [Reference Source site](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,6ca1a80e1f22e519), as mentioned in the comments, and it shows one relatively straightforward implementation using a `foreach` loop that goes over all elements, checks if they're higher than the previous Max, and keeps it for the next iteration.
- An alternate implementation can be found on GitHub, where Microsoft store the [actual code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L2505) for the newer versions of the .NET Core framework. This isn't a reference implementation, but the actual code that goes into CoreFX and the newest versions of the framework. It's also relatively straightforward, but instead of using a foreach loop, it uses `source.GetEnumerator()` to enumerate the values.

I think the github-hosted corefx project is the best place today to learn about implementations of the .NET framework classes, since they're real live production code, rather than potentially unoptimized, simplified or out-of-date reference implementations. You can see a lot of type-specific overloads for specific types (ints, floats, Nullable, and other common types) that allow minor optimizations - like not having to box the temporary variable as an `object`, which make sense for core framework methods that are used by millions of projects. It's a fascinating place to explore to see how things are done internally.

Comment: Note that the Reference Source is also kept up to date with "actual code" - top of the page currently states it's version 4.6.1.  I personally find it much easier to use it's indexing features to navigate quickly to the things I want to find.

Comment: @JamesThorpe True, for now. But it might lag behind in the future, while the github code is, by definition, the latest code. It requires an active action to update the reference site.